# How to enable user to change iptables rules?

Tags: linux, sudo

I am currently developing an application that can automatically run commands in 
multiples servers.

If I change a service configuration I need to restart (or reload) it and thus,
some of the commands need root permission. To make it work I have encrypted and saved the user's password in a text file to use it during sudo commands. I believe that this is a major threat but I didn't want the application to run with root permission either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit which commands user can run via **sudo**. Also, you could provide a *NOPASSWD* option in *sudoers* file in that user's context instead of using the encrypted password "feature".

Here is an example for allowing an unprivileged user to issue the restart of the **iptables** service:

```
geewid  ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/service iptables restart, /sbin/service iptables reload
```

The commands list is comma-separated...

You could also use *Cmnd_Alias* feature:

```
Cmnd_Alias FOOBAR = /sbin/service iptables restart, /sbin/service iptables reload
geewid  ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: FOOBAR
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great... I've edited the answer to show you the *Cmnd_Alias* part.